# React Navigation: Access pages not in TabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have 3 main screen components which are the tabs in my `TabNavigator`: Feed, Discover, and Me. I also have other pages which I need to be able to navigate to from those 3 main pages. However, I can't just nest a `StackNavigator` in my `TabNavigator` because some of my subpages, I need to be able to access from every tab.

This is a lot like how apps like Instagram work. Say for example you're looking at your feed and you tap on someone's username and their page comes up. However, this user's page is also accessible from your user page by finding their username in a list of your followers.

How should I configure my navigation?

Comment: first get a stack navigator and inside that first screen will be having the tab navigator and in the stack navigator screen declare other screens also which you want to open from tab pages. I have 2 different examples of this scenario you can get an idea by running code on your end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please get the idea from these projects I have made.

https://github.com/paraswatts/StackNavigator-inside-TabNavigator

https://github.com/paraswatts/ParasWatts

```
//App.js

/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});
import RootStack from './src/home';
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <RootStack/>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

//home.js


import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Tab from './tab';
import SomeScreen from './somescreen';

const RootStack = StackNavigator({
    Tab: {
      screen: Tab,
    },
    SomeScreen: {
        screen: SomeScreen,
      },
  });

  export default RootStack;

//tab.js

import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Tab1 from './tab1';
import Tab2 from './tab2';
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    Tab1: {
      screen: Tab1,
    },
    Tab2: {
        screen: Tab2,
      },

  });

  export default Tabs;

//tab1.js

/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class Tab1 extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to Tab1!
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{width:300,height:50,borderColor:'#000',borderWidth:2}} onPress={()=>{

            navigate('SomeScreen',{tabno:'one'})
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Go to another screen
        </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {instructions}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});


//tab2.js

/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class Tab2 extends Component {
  render() {            
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation






    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        Welcome to Tab2!
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{width:200,height:50,borderColor:'#000',borderWidth:2}} onPress={()=>{

navigate('SomeScreen',{tabno:'two'})
}}>
<Text>
Go to another screen
</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {instructions}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});


//somescreen.js


/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class SomeScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    const {params} = this.props.navigation.state      
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Coming from Tab Number  {params.tabno}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit App.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {instructions}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Comment: I want to be able to access the subpages from all tabs

Comment: You can access the subpage from any page. First declare a stack navigator instead of tab navigator. Call that stack navigator screen from index or whatever file you have.  In stack navigator first screen will be the Tab navigator screen and other screens will be the subpages you want to open from different tabs.

Comment: I can make an example if you want

Comment: That would be great

Comment: Ok wait for some time.

Comment: I am sharing the solution with you

Comment: I have shared the code hope you get some idea from it

Comment: How would you recommend having the TabBar remain on screen when navigating to the pages that do not have tabs?

Comment: You can have a another stack navigator inside a tab navigator, example of which also I have made. You can check both git projects I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can set tabBarComponent to any react component. This way you can customize your tabbar and you can handle what screen you want to show( in your case only three)

Also you can add any number of screens to you tabNavigator and all those screen will have all the navigator props available. So that you can jump from any screen to any screen. You will have full controll on what to show User as well as navigate to anywhere.